# showing values in datagridview with some condition

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I have a form that contains 1 datagridview and two textboxes and a save button

if the user types a text in textbox1 and leave the second one null it won't show in datagridview1 but will be stored in the database 
and if he wrote in the two textboxes  , their values will appear in datagridview1.

I know the question isn't clear enough but my English isn't fluent.

the code for selecting data is in  class called dta

```
  public DataTable SearchData(string Criterion)
    {
        DataAcessLayer DAL = new DataAcessLayer();
        DAL.open();
        DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Criterion", SqlDbType.VarChar,30);
        param[0].Value = Criterion;
        Dt = DAL.selectdata("SearchData", param);
        DAL.close();
        return Dt;

    }
```

datagridview code

```
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dta.SearchData("");
```

Comment: Please, paste your code here, when you insert and you select data to datagridview.

Comment: i'm asking about the method , is if condition or something else that will handle this .

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro added the code